# How to check whehter rows of a file within the rows of another file

Tags: bash, shell, match

I am fresh to Shell or Bash. I have file1 with one column and about 5000 rows and file2 have five columns with 240k rows. How can I check whether the values of the 5000 rows in file1 within or not the second column of file2?

```
$wc -l file1
$5188
$wc -l file2
$240,888
```

Comment: What do the lines in the first file look like? Are they some form of ID or free text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with awk, something like this:

```
awk 'NR == FNR {a[$2] = $1; next} {if ($2 in a){print(a[$2], $1)}}' file1 file2
```

Basically you read the first file in and store its contents in an array "a". Then you read the second file and check if the second field of each line is contained within array "a" and print it if it is.

My answer assumes your fields are separated by white space, if they are not you will have to change the separator. So, if your fields are separated by commas, you will need:

```
awk -F,       .....
```

Answer (score 0):

The above syntax does work, and it can be further simplified as:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$2; next} {print $1, a[$1]}' file2 file1
```